# Is there a function or process in Power BI that can create a date table that automatically populates each month with sub-categories?

Tags: excel, powerbi

I am relatively new to Power BI and taking over an Excel process that uses a prepopulated (manually) calendar with sub-classifications for each date.  This calendar 'table' then takes the output of a query for each day and adds as such.

I have the query built that provides the data to go into the table, but I am struggling to build the model in the same way within Power BI.  Ideally, I would have a table prepopulated to accept the data each day from the SQL query - for each day in the month. At the end of each month - this table would refresh to the next month with the same classifications so the query can begin inserting.  Again, very new to Power BI - hoping to gain some insight.  Attached is a sample of the existing 'date' table in Excel.  Columns A-F are prepopulated by a user each month and columns G-P are populated with data from the SQL query.  Thanks. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RCHj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few ways to do it, here I tell you from my experiences

First, you can use a reference table which consist of day/date and your sub-classifications for each date
My Grouping or Sub-Classification
https://i.imgur.com/GfKQKzk.png
The Output
https://i.imgur.com/0rrDYl4.png

Second,  you can insert directly your sub-classification on the query itself
here is my example:

[DATE] = my Date data

Query Used:

Date.Day => to extract day number from date
Date.MonthName => to extract Month Name from date

Syntax:

```
each 


if Date.Day([DATE]) >= 1 and Date.Day([DATE]) <= 3 then "01-03" & " " & Date.MonthName([DATE]) else null, type text),
```

The output is the same.